# Sharing domain objects between activities

Tags: android, domain-driven-design, android-activity

I have written my application logic in domain objects (to enable multiple user interfaces and porting to other platforms), and am now lookng at implementing Activities for the user interface.

Considering that each activity needs to serialise its state, what is the best way to ensure my domain objects are only serialised once?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're talking about Serialising object to share them between Activities you should create your own subclass of [`Application`](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/app/Application.html) and store your shared state in there.  A single `Application` object is shared by all the Activities in your app which makes it the perfect place to store *non-persistent* state.  You can get to the `Application` by calling the [`getApplication() method`](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getApplication()) on your `Activity` or `Service`.

You'll need to specify your custom class in the `<application>` tag of your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Any idea how serialising state works for Application subclasses? (I've actually split this off into its own question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041003/saving-application-state)