# Saving Application state

Tags: android

As a follow on from [my question on sharing state between Activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040691/sharing-domain-objects-between-activities), how can I save the instance state of my Application? Since `Application` does not extend `Activity`, there is no `onSaveInstanceState` method to override.

*NB: In advance, this is not a duplicate. Despite its name, [How do I save an Android application’s state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-do-i-save-an-android-applications-state) relates to Activity state*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You **can't** use [`Application.onTerminate()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/app/Application.html#onTerminate()) since there's no guarantee that this will be called.

For the same reason reason you can't use `onStop()` or `onDestroy()` from `Activity` either.

So you'll have to do your save in the [`onPause()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause()) method in every Activity.  Each `Activity` will have a call a `saveState()` you've created in your `Application`.  Since this will get called a lot you will need to make it as efficient as possible, ideally only writing changed data to persistent storage.

You should also note that `onSaveInstanceState()` should be used only for storing the *transient* state of an `Activity`.  For example, if an `Activity` is ended by the user pressing the Back button `onSaveInstanceState()` is not called.  So even if you didn't have shared state, you should still be using `onPause()` to save persistent changes.