# Android strong reference

Tags: android, object

I am having SearchCritiera object and i make it singleton and declare this variable as static,
now problem is if i left my application remain open for couple of hours that static object is removed by Android OS, how can i make sure static object should not be removed by the OS.

like i know there are few keywords like

Weekreference and softreference is there any strongreference keyword which can tell Android OS do not remove the reference ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use static references, even if your application remains in the foreground, these objects may be destroyed by the garbage collector (I've seen this happening a couple times now).

You can simply avoid this by storing them in your unique [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) instance. That object is guaranteed to live as long as your app.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, you can't force Android to keep your application in memory.  If the OS feels it needs more memory for a foreground application or service it reserves the right to terminate one or all of your Activities.

I'm assuming what's happening is your static object is being lost and re-created when you call it, meaning that it has lost its state.  That said, if you have a reference to the object in a foreground Activity I'm a little surprised that it's getting lost.

The best you can do work around this is hook into [the lifecycle events](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#lcycles) and save the state of your singleton object and then restore it when appropriate.

Unfortunately, there are no Application wide lifecycle events in Androd.  Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041003/saving-application-state/2041091#2041091) for how to save transient application state.

Answer (score 1):

If i am not wrong when application remain open for long time data is released by the android OS, and while stopiong activity it will call "onSaveInstanceState" and when can i store searchritiera into this method and will it retrive back when "onRestoreInstanceState" is get called ?

```
private static SearchCriteria searchCriteria;


@Override 
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) 
    {
        outState.putSerializable(WLConstants.SEARCH_CRITERIA, searchCriteria);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState); 
    }
    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if(savedInstanceState != null){
            searchCriteria = (SearchCriteria)
            savedInstanceState.getSerializable(WLConstants.SEARCH_CRITERIA);
        }
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }
```